# ASP MVC give EditorFor element id/name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to specify an `@Html.EditorFor` view element in some jQuery code I'm using (`datepicker`). Is it possible to give a specific `EditorFor` element a name or id?

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTaken)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTaken)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that your datepicker is being used on a text field? Also assuming that by 'EditorMessageFor,' you mean `EditorFor`.

If both of my assumptions are correct, you can use `TextBoxFor` instead, like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTaken, new { id = "MyCssId" })
```

Failing that, you'd have to create a custom editor template. There's a comprehensive guide to doing just that [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html).